# Create a global validate_date function in DateTimeHelper.php to use that function in all laravel.php controllers

Tags: php, laravel

I have separate validate_date functions in controller1.php, controller2.php, and controller3.php. I want to create a global function in DateTimeHelper.php to validate dates instead of creating a function in each controller for this functionality. I am using Laravel in the backend
Controller1:

```
private function validate_date($date)
{
    $split_date = explode('/', $date);
    if (count($split_date) == 3) {
        return checkdate($split_date [0], $split_date [1], $split_date [2]);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Controller2 && controller 3:

```
private function validate_date($date)
{
    if ($this->check_field($date) && $date !== 'Invalid date') {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

My problem is that I am using different functions in different controllers, I need a global function to validate dates instead of creating a function in each controller for this functionality.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Then do so. If they work differently, then create two different functions.

Comment: I am fairly new to this framework. if I create a global function in DateTimeHelper.php, How am I supposed to access that function in other controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method will probably do what you're looking for:

Create a new file called `DateTimeHelper.php` inside a (new) Helpers folder. The final path will be app\Helpers\DateTimeHelper.php.

The content of DateTimeHelper.php will look like:

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;

class DateTimeHelper {
    public function validate()
    {
    }

    public function checkField()
    {
    }
}
```

Now edit the controllers where you want to use the class, add a procted property $dateTimeHelper and use Laravel's [Automatic Injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container#automatic-injection) like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Helpers\DateTimeHelper;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    protected $dateTimeHelper;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @param  DateTimeHelper  $dateTimeHelper
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(DateTimeHelper $dateTimeHelper)
    {
        $this->dateTimeHelper = $dateTimeHelper;
    }

    public function show($date)
    {
        return $this->dateTimeHelper->validate($date);
    }
}
```

Hopefully this should solve the problem, however, I'd recommend to look into [Laravel validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation).

Comment: Glad that worked for you. If you're new to laravel and your aim is to validate Requests, then I'd recommend to use some of the laravel built-in validation. There's a link at the bottom of my answer .
Good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

How about a Service Class instead of helper function and put all possible date validation from the system into this Service Class?